# Why is my UI not updating after first run? (Android)

Tags: android, user-interface, retrofit

My UI is acting very funny and after a lot of research I still don't know why.

I retrieve some data from Internet and present it to the user. The thing is that, on first load, everything works (data retrieved and correctly shown). After that, when the onClickListeners execute, the UI would not update (data is retrieved and applied to the Views, but Views wouldn't update). But then, if I change the fragment (transition) and after that come back to my fragment, everything works just fine (Views will update when onClickListener actions are executed).

The data is retrieved using RetroFit library.

What I have already tried: update other generic Views (like TextView, for instance), to discard the problem is MyView (MyProgressBar) class, update UI somewhere else in the code (outside RetroFit methods, at the very end of onResponse inside RetroFit, etc), using AsyncTask and putting RetroFit stuff inside there, calling invalidate and postInvalidate. No response: I always get the same result described.
I have debugged the code: everything executes as expected, including the lines that update the UI. Response comes from the server, results are all correct and applied to the Views, but they wouldn't update.

Please, help!

PS: The app has other fragments very similar to this. They all work just fine, but this is the "home" one, so the other load after this one. It looks like calling onDestroy of one fragment is what makes the others work, which makes no sense but maybe gives a clue.

Here is my class (simplified):

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

Activitys dayActivity; // An object to retreive from Internet API

private MyProgressBar stepProgress, walkingProgress, cyclingProgress, exerciseProgress, otherProgress,
        standingProgress, restingProgress; // Custom made Views
private TextView dateTextView,lastSyncTextView;
private View v; // The view where the Fragment is hosted
private Calendar calendar; // Store the date I am working on

public HomeFragment() {
    this.calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
}

public static HomeFragment getInstance(Date date) {
    HomeFragment r = new HomeFragment();

    r.calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    r.calendar.setTime(date);

    return r;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.daily_progress_activity, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Set Date to today if needed
    if (this.calendar == null)
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    android.text.format.DateFormat dateFormat = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
    shownDate = dateFormat.format(DATE_FORMAT, calendar).toString();

    setupUi();

    //Get Retrofit Instance(API)
    Retrofit retrofit = ApiHelper.getClient();
    userClient = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);
    //API Request and set Progressbars
    getActivityData();

}

/**
 * connect UI with controller
 */
private void setupUi() {

    v = getView();
    stepProgress = (MyProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.dai_pb_pbSteps);
    walkingProgress = (MyProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.dai_pb_pbWalking);
    cyclingProgress = (MyProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.dai_pb_pbCycling);
    exerciseProgress = (MyProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.dai_pb_pbExercise);
    otherProgress = (MyProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.dai_pb_pbOthers);
    standingProgress = (MyProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.dai_pb_pbStanding);
    restingProgress = (MyProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.dai_pb_pbResting);
    //SyncTime
    lastSyncTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dai_pb_tvLastSync);
    //Date
    dateTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dailyTextViewDate);
    writeDateOverCircle();

    checkRightAngleVisibility();

    // With the left angle we go to the previous date
    // TODO: Start reseting progressBars, so if there is no data loaded, it will show all gray
    ImageView letfAngle = v.findViewById(R.id.dailyAngleLeft);
    letfAngle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Push left");
            // Calculate previous day
            HomeFragment.this.calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            // Store it in showDate
            android.text.format.DateFormat dateFormat = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
            shownDate = dateFormat.format(DATE_FORMAT, calendar).toString();
            writeDateOverCircle();
            checkRightAngleVisibility();
            // Call getActivityData
            getActivityData();
        }
    });

    // With the right angle we go to the next date (if possible)
    // TODO: Start reseting progressBars, so if there is no data loaded, it will show all gray
    ImageView rightAngle = v.findViewById(R.id.dailyAngleRight);
    rightAngle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar calendar = HomeFragment.this.calendar; // Make the calendar easy to access
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // Go to next date
            // Store it in showDate
            android.text.format.DateFormat dateFormat = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
            shownDate = dateFormat.format(DATE_FORMAT, calendar).toString();
            writeDateOverCircle();
            checkRightAngleVisibility();
            // Call getActivityData
            getActivityData();
        }
    });

    // Several views will have the same OnClickListener, so we create this and the apply it to
    // these views
    View.OnClickListener goToWeekView = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment frag = HomeFragmentWeekly.getInstance(HomeFragment.this.calendar.getTime());
            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_home_fragment, frag);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    };
    v.findViewById(R.id.dayProgressCircleLeft).setOnClickListener(goToWeekView);
    v.findViewById(R.id.dayProgressCircleRight).setOnClickListener(goToWeekView);
    v.findViewById(R.id.dai_pb_tvWeekly).setOnClickListener(goToWeekView);
    v.findViewById(R.id.textViewDaily).setOnClickListener(goToWeekView);
    v.findViewById(R.id.dailyTextViewDate).setOnClickListener(goToWeekView);

    // When the user swipes the finger to the left, goes to the daily pie chart view
    v.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getContext()) {
      public void onSwipeLeft() {
            Fragment frag = HomeFragmentPieChart.getInstance(HomeFragment.this.calendar.getTime());
            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_home_fragment, frag);
            transaction.commit();
        }
      });
}

/**
 * Paints the date over the top circle, checking that everything fits
 */
private void writeDateOverCircle() {
    // Try with the month's full name and see what happens
    String month = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    dateTextView.setText(day + " " + month);

    // If the dateTextView is too wide, then redo with a shorter month name
    // To get the measures with safety, you need to use getMeasuredWidth. For it to work, you have to do a .meassure first
    dateTextView.measure(0,0);
    int dateWidth = dateTextView.getMeasuredWidth();
    View circle = v.findViewById(R.id.dayProgressCircleLeft);
    circle.measure(0,0);
    int circleWidth = circle.getMeasuredWidth();
    if (dateWidth > circleWidth-16) {
        month = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
        month = month + ".";
    }
    dateTextView.setText(day + " " + month);
}

/**
 * Makes the right angle invisible is we are already in today's date, because we shouldn't be able
 * to navigate to the future
 */
private void checkRightAngleVisibility() {
    ImageView rightAngle = v.findViewById(R.id.dailyAngleRight);
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Reset the time of the day in today
    today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if (today.after(this.calendar))
        rightAngle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        rightAngle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

/**
 * API request and set the Progressbar and TextView
 */
private void getActivityData() {
    Call<ResponseProgress> call = userClient.getProgress(projKey, patKey, shownDate, dayCount);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseProgress>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseProgress> call, Response<ResponseProgress> response) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Get Data");
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.body().toString());
                //Get Activity Values
                dayActivity = response.body().getValue().getData()[0].getValues();
                //Steps
                HomeFragment.this.dayStepsCount = dayActivity.getActivityStepsCount();
                //Walking
                HomeFragment.this.dayWalkingTime = dayActivity.getActivityWalkingTime();
                //Cycling
                HomeFragment.this.dayCyclingTime = dayActivity.getActivityCyclingTime();
                //Exercise
                HomeFragment.this.dayExerciseTime = dayActivity.getActivityExerciseTime();
                //Other
                HomeFragment.this.dayOtherTime = dayActivity.getActivityOtherTime();
                //Standing
                HomeFragment.this.dayStandingTime = dayActivity.getActivityStandingTime();
                //Resting
                HomeFragment.this.dayRestingTime = dayActivity.getActivityrestingtime();

                syncTime(); // I tried commenting this line. Same results.
                putDataToUI();  // This is the call that is causing no effect
            } else {
                ErrorHelper error = new ErrorHelper();
                ErrorMessage errorMessage = error.help(response.errorBody());
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), errorMessage.getStatus_msg(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseProgress> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
/**
 * Get last SyncTime from Sensor. To see the data are up to date or not.
 */
private void syncTime() {
    Call<ResponseSensors> call = userClient.getSensors(HelperShared.loadString(getContext(),
            Constants.PREF_TOKEN), HelperShared.loadString(getContext(), Constants.PREF_ORGID),
            HelperShared.loadString(getContext(), Constants.PREF_PROJ_ID));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseSensors>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseSensors> call, Response<ResponseSensors> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sensor: " + response.body().getValue().
                        getSensorWithShortName(sensorShortName).getLast_synced_timestamp());
                String lastSync = response.body().getValue().
                        getSensorWithShortName(sensorShortName).getLast_synced_timestamp();
                lastSyncTextView.setText(lastSync);
            } else {
                ErrorHelper error = new ErrorHelper();
                ErrorMessage errorMessage = error.help(response.errorBody());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), errorMessage.getStatus_msg(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseSensors> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FEhler: " + t.getMessage());

        }
    });
}

private void putDataToUI() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Set Progress");
    //Steps
    setProgressBar(stepProgress, stepGoal, stepProg, this.dayStepsCount);
    //Walking
    setProgressBar(walkingProgress, walkingGoal, walkingProg, this.dayWalkingTime);
    //Cycling
    setProgressBar(cyclingProgress, cyclingGoal, cyclingProg, this.dayCyclingTime);
    //Exercise
    setProgressBar(exerciseProgress, exerciseGoal, exerciseProg, this.dayExerciseTime);
    //Other
    setProgressBar(otherProgress, otherGoal, otherProg, this.dayOtherTime);
    //Standing
    setProgressBar(standingProgress, standingGoal, standingProg, this.dayStandingTime);
    //Resting
    setProgressBar(restingProgress, restingGoal, restingProg, this.dayRestingTime);

    // Here I tried v.invalidate() and v.postInvalidate(). No results.
    // Also tried to invalidate and postInvalidate each MyProgressBar. No results.
}


/**
 * @param progBar       Progressbar to set the values
 * @param goal          daily goal the user has to reach
 * @param activityValue the value form the API for the spacific activity
 */
private void setProgressBar(MyProgressBar progBar, float goal, float progGoal, float activityValue) {
    float value = (100 / progGoal) * activityValue;
    float dailyGoal = (100 / progGoal) * goal;
    progBar.setSecondaryProgress((int) dailyGoal);
    if (value >= 100) {
        progBar.setProgress(100);
    } else {
        progBar.setProgress((int) value);
    }
    if (progBar != stepProgress) {
        int houers = (int) activityValue / 60;
        int minutes = (int) activityValue % 60;
        progBar.setTagText(houers + "h:" + minutes + "min");
    } else {
        progBar.setTagText((int) activityValue + "");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting value in `setProgressBar` method when you click

Comment: Yes. onClickListener calls getActivityData, and this calls putDataToUI which executes the setProgressBars.

Comment: Did you try to call on UI thread? and also  check stepGoal, stepProg, dayStepsCount not null or empty

Comment: Tried to run on UI thread, no results. I added this inside onResponse:
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            putDataToUI();
                        }
                    });

Comment: Values and objects are ok: no null or empties around.

Comment: Would you try initialise your views inside onStart() rather than onActivityCreated(). I do that.

Comment: I did, and even in onResume. No results. And the funny thing is that the UI reacts ok and updates on first start, so the call inside onActivityCreated (and onResume given the case) works. The next ones (inside onClickListeners) are the ones causing no result. But they will work (and cause result) after changing fragment and coming back to the problematic fragment.

Comment: Do you mean to imply that the call to `syncTime()` works correctly?

Comment: Usually when you debug and everything looks like it's working, that's because you're looking at stale objects that are no longer attached to the view hierarchy. I suppose you've verified that `onCreateView()` only executes once, meaning it is not possible two or more instances of `stepProgress` (for example) have been created?

Comment: You're right! onCreateView is accessed twice on first run, and then only one when I go back to the fragment. Now I have to find out why... Thanks for the clue, @greeble31

Comment: You may want to look into [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), and update that from the `onResponse()` callback instead, as a way of addressing some of your scoping problems.

Comment: I solved it! The fragment was initially created twice: once in the xml (class="myFragmentClass") and another one inside onActivityCreated of the parent fragment. Once I cancelled this second creation, everything works just fine. Anyway I would like to know how to update my ViewModel inside onResponse (just to learn). I tried to read about it, but got more lost (only people talking about creating my own ViewModel). May you give me some hint, @greeble31.

Comment: As long as you've got it working correctly, that's the most important thing. I was mainly worried about the `Callback<ResponseProgress>` getting bound to an old `HomeFragment`, but I think your fix is probably sufficient, and using `ViewModel` or not is just a matter of taste at this point.